# python import module global local namespace

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I have a problem understanding how import is working when call in function. I believe it's related to scope but I can't figure out how it works. I've checked similar questions on the site or some tutorials but it looks like I just don't understand how it works

I have a python script MyScipt.py containing

```
def usage(errorID):
    # import sys
    if errorID == 0:
        print("blah blah blah")
    print("blah blah blah")
    print("blah blah blah"+\
    sys.exit()

def main():
    import sys
    # print(len(sys.argv),sys.argv)
    try:
        rootDir = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        usage(0)

# MAIN PROGRAM
#
if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

the execution is failing with

> PS D:\xxx\python> python .\myScript.py blah blah blah blah blah blah
>   blah blah blah Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   ".\myScript.py", line 288, in main
>       rootDir = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\myScript.py", line 299,
>   in 
>       main()   File ".\myScript.py", line 290, in main
>       usage(0)   File ".\myScript.py", line 15, in usage
>       sys.exit() NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

If I uncomment the 2nd line (# import sys), it'll work

How can I make an import available to all function within my script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not importing `import sys` at toplevel _before_ all function definitions?

Comment: Indeed it was the initial position I want to write the code but then I got messed up with 'where should I place the call to `import os.path`'. I'll mark this question as answer and probably open a new one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import sys at the top of the file instead of in the function.

```
import sys
def usage(errorID):

    if errorID == 0:
        print("blah blah blah")
    print("blah blah blah")
    print("blah blah blah"+\
    sys.exit()

def main():
    import sys
    # print(len(sys.argv),sys.argv)
    try:
        rootDir = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        usage(0)

# MAIN PROGRAM
#
if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

You are getting the second error because you are not passing any arguments to the script and then sys is not defined so you cannot `sys.exit()`

Comment: You're right. This is where I wanted to put it first but things got messy while trying to use os.path method. I think I should open another question.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your feedback.
`import sys` statement must be placed at the beginning of the script to solve this error